# How to convert a JSON object (returns from google places API) to a Java object

Tags: java, json, gson, google-places-api, unmarshalling

Google places API returns a JSON when it requested for a place under food category which includes the details of several places.

I want to create an object array where each object contains details of a specific place.

I have used GSON library for my implementation and it works fine for a dummy JSON object but not with the JSON result given from Google place API and 'JsonSyntaxException' is thrown.

I look for a solution for following matters..
1 How can I proceed with GSON and given JSON object to create my object array or
2 Is there any other way to accomplish my task (still using JSON result)

Thanks.

**update**
**Class PlaceObject**

```
import java.util.List;

public class PlaceObject {
    private List<String> results;
}
```

**Class JSONconverter**

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import com.google.gson.Gson;

public class JSONconverter {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

Gson gson = new Gson();

try {

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
        new FileReader("c:\\placeAPI.json"));

    //convert the json string back to object
    PlaceObject obj = gson.fromJson(br, PlaceObject.class);
    //obj.results = null ,when debugged thats the problem
    System.out.println("Result: " + obj);

    } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }

    }
}
```

**The link of JSON**

http://www.mediafire.com/?8mmnuxuopimhdnz

Comment: Please provide a sample JSON you get from the Google Places API, the code of the objects you got so far and the exception message, so we can help you.

Comment: I would expect that the Google API is supplying valid JSON and the GSON library is capable of parsing it.  Most likely you've somehow messed up connecting the two.  As Jan G said, provide an example of the JSON source and the actual error messages you're getting.

Comment: Thnks for comments/answers.please use following link to get the JSON (you may have to add a key)      https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=500&types=food&name=harbour&sensor=false&key=AddYourOwnKeyHere                                     Here is the exception {Exception in thread "main" com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected a string but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 6 column 8
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:176)
}

Comment: why don't you include some sample output here?  also, what do your java objects look like?

Comment: Please include the JSON here, or at least provide a valid link.

Comment: @HotLicks I have updated my question with classes and the link for JSON object.

Comment: I've never sat down and figured out how to use GSON, but I'm relatively certain you're not using it correctly.  "PlaceObject" looks nothing like your JSON input.

Answer (score 2):

I like working with [gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/)

btw. there is another relevant [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/338586/a-better-java-json-library)

Comment: This is a great library.  I can't say enough good things about it.

Answer (score 1):

Jersey client's documentation proposes to use Jackson library ([see wiki](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonDataBinding))

Answer (score 1):

You can also take a look at Genson library http://code.google.com/p/genson/.
It provides an out of box integration with jersey. You only need to have the jar in your classpath.